# Replacing mutliple characters using a switch Statement in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

New to Javascript and JQuery. I saw this little code on replacing a character (in this example replace a comma with a period).

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="in2"><br/><br/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#in2").keyup(function (evt) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g, ".");
});
```

What if I wanted to replace mutliple characters like example open bracket, semi-colon and so on. How would i accomplish that using a switch statment?

Comment: why would you use a `switch` statement? Just chain multiple `.replace` calls.

Comment: add more details like replace from character and to character

Comment: If you wanted to replace a bunch of characters with a space, for example, you can use a regex.

Comment: It largely depends whether you want to replace with the same value or not. If you need to replace the same value, just make a **single regex**, otherwise, you may want to create an array of rulesets and apply all of them sequentially: https://jsfiddle.net/j23a5hts/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#in2").keyup(function (evt) {
    this.value = this.value.replace("(", ".").replace(/,/g, ".");
});
```

you can use as many replace as you want or you can convert your string to array and then use replace.